# Standalone deployment in wildfly 10 is not deploying on single node

Tags: wildfly-10

I am using wildfly 10, and trying to use its standalone deployment feature  --  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Singleton+deployments

According to the above link, I have included /META-INF/singleton-deployment.xml, inside my web application's war file. singleton-deployment.xml is having below configuration --

```
<singleton-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:singleton-deployment:1.0"/>
```

Also, I have setup the Master slave group of jboss servers according to below link ---

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Clustering+and+Domain+Setup+Walkthrough

Now when I am trying to deploy the war file (in other-server-group of my cluster, which is having full-ha profile) it is getting deployed to all the nodes (master as well as slave). But according to singleton deployment documentation, the respected file should get deploy to only single node and in case of failure of that node, deployment should happen to another node.